# Pygame Window Different sizes

Tags: python, pygame

I am having trouble with my pygame window. I have set it to pygame.FULLSCREEN and when I run it from IDLE and press f5, I get a the correct size/scale. However, when I run it from cmd, I get a version of my game that is too large. Is there any way I can make sure I get the size I get when I run from IDLE instead of cmd or text editor?

I had my game print out pygame.display.Info() for both and they were the same:

```
<VideoInfo(hw = 0, wm = 1,video_mem = 0
     blit_hw = 0, blit_hw_CC = 0, blit_hw_A = 0,
     blit_sw = 0, blit_sw_CC = 0, blit_sw_A = 0,
     bitsize  = 32, bytesize = 4,
     masks =  (16711680, 65280, 255, 0),
     shifts = (16, 8, 0, 0),
     losses =  (0, 0, 0, 8),
     current_w = 1920, current_h = 1080>
```

Comment: You can write that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105750/pygame-fullsreen-display-issue found the answer here. If someone else runs into this problem. Make sure you are using:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```